# Typescript - unable to create new Date from timestamp

Tags: typescript

I've started to work with typescript and I'm unable to create a new Date using an epoch timestamp.

```
let isoDate: Date = new Date(1544513287*1000);
```

Or I try

```
let isoDate: Date = new Date(1544513287);
```

But the value of isoDate is always `Sun Jan 18 1970 23:01:53 GMT+0200 (IST)` 
Please advise, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

from the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> ```
> new Date(value)
> ```
>
> value Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since
>   January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch;
>   but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

where

```
new Date(1544513287*1000)
```

outputs

> Tue Dec 11 2018 09:28:07 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

to see the format:

```
new Date().getTime()
//1544514129965
```

Comment: I tried doing *1000, I still get the same response.